# Problem with portuguese babel

Tags: babel

Could you help me?
I'm using these packages for portuguese babel:`\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[portuges]{babel}`
In all thesis it reconise the accentuation. but not in the Appendix. when I try to use these packages `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` it doesn't work.

The full thesis codes are:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[compress,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}

\includeonly{intro,emergente2,modeloteorico,revempirica,metodologia,analisempirica,analisempiricaregrasPM,analisempiricaregrasPO,Conclusao,append}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\input{coverpage}
\input{frontpage}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\onehalfspacing

\include{intro}
\part{An\'{a}lise te\'{o}rica}  
\include{emergente2}
\include{modeloteorico}
\part{Estima\c{c}\~{a}o dos efeitos das pol\'{i}ticas na economia}
\include{revempirica}
\include{metodologia}
\include{analisempirica}
\part{Estima\c{c}\~{a}o das regras de pol\'{i}tica}
\include{analisempiricaregrasPM}
\include{analisempiricaregrasPO}
\include{Conclusao}
\part*{Ap\^{e}ndices}
\include{append}

\bibliography{tese_biblio1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografias}
\bibliographystyle{mybibstyle}

\end{document}
```

the codes for Appendix are

```
\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Ap\^{e}ndices}
\setcounter{equation}{0}

\chapter{Dados e estatisticas descretivas} \label{appch:dadosestatistica}
```

Could you tell me what's go on?

Comment: The most probable cause is that the appendix file is not Latin-1 encoded.

Comment: Not the problem but you definitely should be using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. (You don't have to use the `utf8` option for `inputenc` to benefit from the T1 encoding.)

Comment: @egreg - How can I make it Latin-1 encoded? is it possible?

Comment: @Gilson That's a problem with your text editor program.